# the set and class does not name a type

Tags: c++, c++11

In peca1 and par1, lines 7,8 and 9, my program return: peca1, par1 does not name a type.

```
#include "Piece.hpp"
#include "doctest.h"

Piece peca1 = Piece("N", "a4", "c3");
std::pair<int, int> par1;

par1.first = int("c"%97);
par1.second = 3;
peca1.checkMovements();

TEST_CASE("TESTE N-check"){
    CHECK(peca1.currentPosition == par1);
}
```

Comment: You can't put statements outside of functions. Move the three erroring lines inside your test case.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: What is `int("c"%97)` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using Catch2. See this tutorial [https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md#test-cases-and-sections][1]

As @Quentin mentioned, move the setups into TEST_CASE. I would also recommend adding sections as shown in the tutorial. Catch runs the setup for every section.